# Cypher match exactly by properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have a node in the database with label L and multiple random properties A=B, C=D, etc. I want to merge another node in the database also with label L but **only** has the properties A=B.

With current Cypher, I could just do a simple:

```
 merge (node:L {A:B}) return node
```

But since match/merge considers any nodes with those properties count, it will be merged into the first node. Is there any way to get this **exact** match? I was thinking of doing something like a

```
merge (node:L {props}) where {props} == {all node's props}
```

but that functionality to list all the node's props doesn't exist though it's on their [top five ideas](https://trello.com/c/FciCdgWl/7-cypher-property-container-functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the properties you want to compare this will do the trick.

```
MATCH (node:L {a: "a"}) 
WHERE LENGTH(KEYS(node)) = 1 
WITH (CASE COUNT(node) WHEN 0 then [1] END) AS X 
FOREACH (x in X | create (a:L {a:"a"}));
```

The number on the LENGTH line must be equal to the number of properties you want to compare, at this case, one.

```
LENGTH(KEYS(node)) = 1
```

## EDIT 1 - Same query but returning the node

```
MATCH (node:L {a: "a"}) 
WHERE LENGTH(KEYS(node)) = 1 
WITH (CASE COUNT(node) WHEN 0 then [1] END) AS X 
FOREACH (x in X | create (a:L {a:"a"})) 
with X
MATCH (node:L {a: "a"}) return node;
```

Comment: Just tested this out. Didn't know about the keys() function

Comment: Question: is there a way to rewrite this like the merge function where it returns either the new node or the node already in there?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to do that. You can return X and inspect its value. It is returning [1] if the node was created or null if it already exists. Maybe with that information you could try to run another query to get the desired node.

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly which property names you want to exclude when determining if there are any matches (prior to creating a node), you can do something like the following. In this example, the properties to exclude when determining if there is a match are "C", "D", and "E".

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (node:L {A: "B"})
WHERE NOT (has(node.C) OR has(node.D) OR has(node.E))
WITH (CASE WHEN node IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END) AS cn
FOREACH (x IN cn | CREATE (:L {A: "B"}))
RETURN cn[0];
```

The returned value will be `1` if the node was created, or `null` if it was not.

Comment: Thanks but I definitely do not know the properties I want to exclude, only the properties I want to include.